# Use Grizzly as a web service engine

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, grizzly

I'm try to create a Grizzly web service engine but some elements are missing.

**Here is what I would like to do:**

- Create a Grizzly server as an executable jar (this is ok)
- This server would must be able to look into a folder for web service archives (contained in a jar or a war or other)
- The server should expose this web services.

**What I already know :**

- web services can be built as servlet (It seems that Grizzly is able to run servlets but I did not find anything about how to load an external serlvet contained in a ".war" or other)
- I tried to use a ClassLoader to load a JAX-RS2 webservice exported in a ".jar" but the @path binding did not work (I might have missed something)

**What I would like to know :**

- Which type of archive should I use for the web service archives ?
- Should the web services be servlets ? In these case, how to dynamicaly load a servlet with Grizzly ?
- Am I going in the wrong direction ?

**Here is what I have done with the classloader**

```
File file  = new File("c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\myresource.jar");
 URL url = file.toURI().toURL();  
 URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
 ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName ("Test.ExternalWS.MyResource", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("getIt");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance ();
Object result = method.invoke (instance);
this.WSInstance = classToLoad.newInstance();
```

- Here is the webservice

  @Path("myresource")
  public class MyResource {

  ```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getIt() {
      return "Got it!";
  }
  ```

  }

Nothing happens when I try to reach localhost:8080/....../myresource.

I tried all possible urls and put a breakpoint... never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which Jersey version you're using.
In Jersey 2 I made it work this way:

```
    File file = new File("/path/resource1.jar");
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, Main.class.getClassLoader());

    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .setClassLoader(cl)
            .files("/path/resource1.jar");
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
            BASE_URI, rc);
```

May be there is more elegant way...

Comment: Thank you Alexey.

I did not know about the setClassLoader() and the files() methods of resourceConfig.

I had a look at Jersey documentation and it is not specified that a classloader is required to use files().


I try to only use files() and I got these error :

A class file of the class name, com.MyWS.MyResource is identified but the class could not be found.

Interesting.

Comment: I am going to go deeper on this files() method.  
  
It is not very easy to find some documentation.  
  
Even Jersey documentation is not very rich on this.  
  
I will make another post later, when I will know more.

Comment: By  the way, yes I am using the last version of Jersey : 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Grizzly 1.x or 2.x branch ?

I develop Grizzly Deployer in Grizzly 1.x.  You should check the source code if it does what you need